# Mounting an External HD Accessible Through Finder

Tags: mac, finder, external-disk, high-sierra, mount

Good Afternoon All,

I am attempting to mount an external hard drive using ext4fuse.   I have installed ext4fuse using the following:

```
brew tap homebrew/fuse
brew install Caskroom/cask/osxfuse
brew install ext4fuse

mkdir /Volumes/Linux
ext4fuse /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/Linux
```

This seems to work without issue and I can view the contents using sudo su, but not without.

I followed the instruction on another post which states:

"*IMPORTANT: with ext4fuse by default you'll only be able to mount and see your files with sudo. To mount as regular user add your user to the operator group with sudo dscl . append /Groups/operator GroupMembership . Once you've done this you will be able to mount as a regular user and see the files from Finder.*"

Even following this instruction I have been unable to access this location from finder.

I would appreciate any help getting this problem fixed.

Thanks in advance.
Scott

Answer (score -1):

ext4fuse /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/Linux -o allow_other

Try with the '-o allow_other' argument? At least I can view my Ubuntu home dir in this way.

You may also want to use sudo.

Comment: We are looking for answers which solve the problem, not just list of things to try without further explanations on what the commands do.

Comment: This works on my Mac Book Pro but not my Mac Book Air.  I have set up the permissions the same on both machines.  Is there a way to troubleshoot this issue?